# How to set default values for an Entity when it is created?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, default-value

I was asked to make a JPA Entity bean so, that when it is created it gets default values for certain properties. What I did was setting values to those properties in the code before persisting the entity to the database but I was told that it is the wrong practice. I have default values in the database for columns for those properties but when a new entity is created, they get no default values.

What is the normal way to approach this? I can't find proper documentation for it by googling around.

Comment: *when it is created it gets default values for certain properties*: so, initialize the properties from within the constructor. That's what is called when you create an entity, just like any other object.

Comment: I see. Kind of strange that I haven't yet bumped into constructors in Entities.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will be following a practice that there will be repository and repositoryImpl for persisting or retriving the data.

So create a method called wire(Object o)/bind(Object o) etc for every repositary and set the default values with in the created method. Whenever you are saving the data, 
1) call the created method and then call the save method
2) call the save method within the created method, whenever you want to save the data dont use direct save/persist of entitymanager, always call the created wire()/bind() and in that method call the save/persist.

Hope that will help you.